# Django. Увеличения значения поля в модели

Tags: python, django

Застрял вроде на таком простом моменте, но тем не менее. В гугле ничего не нашел. Ситуация такая, нужно чтобы пользователь вводил некое число и это значение, что он ввел прибавлялось к уже имеющему значению некоторому полю в модели.

Из кода, что приведен ниже необходимо, что когда пользователь вводит в поля development и testing цифры, эти цифры не обновлялись, а прибавлялись к уже имеющим значениям в базе, которые были до них.

Пример: в базе в полях development и testing хранятся значения 10 и 15, пользователь вводит в одно поля 5, в другое 3, и тогда в базе обновляются значения до 15 и 18 соответственно.

Скажем, так, вот модель:

```
Class Project(models.Model):

    company = models.ForeignKey('projects.Company', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='projects')

    title = models.CharField('Project title', max_length=128)

    development = models.DecimalField('development hours', default=0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)

    testing = models.DecimalField('testing hours', default=0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)
```

Вот форма:

```
class ProjectForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['development', 'testing']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'UPDATE'))
```

View:

```
class ProjectUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Project
    form_class = ProjectForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

html

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card bg-light">
            <div class="card-body">
                {% crispy form %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно переопределить один из методов в `UpdateView`. Наверное это должен быть `form_valid()`. То есть на этапе, когда форма валидная, мы берем существующие данные из объекта и добавляем их в соответствующие поля экземпляра формы.

Я не проверял работает код или нет, но вы хотя бы будете знать в каком направлении двигаться.

```
class ProjectUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Project
    form_class = ProjectForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.development += self.object.development
        form.instance.testing += self.object.testing

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Спасибо! То, что надо!